# In bonding, do I adjust settings (e.g. number/size of RX queues) directly on master bond interface or on slave eth interfaces?

Tags: networking, bonding

Say that I have following bond configuration:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
  bond-master bond0

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
  bond-master bond0

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
  address 172.16.0.11
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  bond-mode 802.3ad
  bond-miimon 100
  bond-lacp-rate 1
  bond-slaves none
```

In [this tutorial](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/06/22/monitoring-tuning-linux-networking-stack-receiving-data/#tuning-network-devices), it is well explained that if I want to, for example, set the number of RX queues to 8 for `eth0`, I would do:

```
sudo ethtool -L eth0 combined 8
```

That's perfectly fine with me if I only have `ethX` interfaces. I could adjust and tune them one by one. But what confuses me is what if `eth0` is slave in the bonding setup from the beginning. How do I adjust these settings then? Do I go one by one `ethX` (i.e. physical NICs) or I do it on the `bondX` encompassing them? Is it even possible/reasonable to change it directly on bond interface?

Comment: If you are running on a recent Debian version then you better look up `teamd` and `teamctl`. Bonding is deprecated.

Comment: @val0x00ff - Thanks for your suggestion, however, that is not an option currently. I have asked this question mainly to understand the concept.